# Could not find driver with class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, centos, jira

**Goal:**
My purpose is to connect jira to my own database. OK, i read the documentation https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/connecting-jira-applications-to-mysql-802592179.html and still having problems. Am I missing something?
**Problem:**
On a centos7 x64 server, root access, during the first setup web UI (localhost:8080) I am getting this error after hitting the test connection button: `Could not find driver with class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
**Workaround:**
Path Variables :
1. `JAVA_HOME : /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el7_2.x86_64`
2. `PATH : /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el7_2.x86_64/bin`
3. Reboot
4. Same error: Could not find driver with class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Found the solution.
Had to reboot all system, not only restarting jira service after copying the driver files into lib. An error prevents jira to start properly.

Thanks again.

Comment: Did you add mysql-connector.jar in your project lib? If not, you need to add it.

Comment: @MickaëlB no, this one is just a little bit different, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [mysql-connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html) and add it the the lib Directory of your tomcat in which jira is running

Answer (score 1):

Download mysql connector jar file from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html and add it in your project's lib.